# Hook not updating when being called in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having problem with updating state after retrieving data from my API. The API response is just fine but for some reason my weatherData-hook does not update and returns undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
const renderForecastTable = ({ weatherData }) => (
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Tid</th><th>Temperatur</th><th>Vind</th><th>Nederbörd</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {
        weatherData.Map(hour => 
            <tr>
                <td>{hour.Time}</td><td>{hour.Temp}</td>
                <td>{hour.WindSpeed} m/s {hour.WindDirection} grader</td>
                <td>{hour.AvgPrecipitationIntensity} mm</td>
            </tr>)
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
)

const Weather = (props) => {
    const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const location = useLocation();

    useEffect(() => {
        const getWeather = async () => {
            const response = await fetch(`weather`);
            const json = await response.json();
            setWeatherData(json);
            setLoading(false);
        }
        getWeather();
    }, [])

    return(
        loading ? <></> : renderForecastTable(weatherData)
    )
}

export default Weather;
```

JSON-response:

```
[
  {"time":"4/9/2021 8:00:00 AM","temp":"6","windDirection":"216","windSpeed":"8.7","avgPrecipitationIntensity":"0"},
  {"time":"4/9/2021 9:00:00 AM","temp":"5.5","windDirection":"213","windSpeed":"7.9","avgPrecipitationIntensity":"0.2"},
  {"time":"4/9/2021 10:00:00 AM","temp":"4.7","windDirection":"218","windSpeed":"7.1","avgPrecipitationIntensity":"0.3"},
  {"time":"4/9/2021 11:00:00 AM","temp":"5.5","windDirection":"214","windSpeed":"7.3","avgPrecipitationIntensity":"0.3"},
  ...
]
```

Comment: are you sure that response.json() is not undefined? By the way you can define function outside useEffect and use only getWeather() inside, it is more clean

Comment: `getWeather`is an async function, so I guess you have to await it?

Comment: @Sowam Yes, when I console.log json the correct response is shown. Good input on defining the function outside, cheers!

Comment: @Norse Can't await in useEffect as it isn't async

Comment: @claytonnes maybe there is something wrong in renderForecastTable function? because it is really weird that const json has something but right after it doesn't set a hook ... it is also hard to find a solution when we cannot test it

Comment: Included the renderForecastTable in code of the post!

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive, so here `weatherData.Map(hour => ...`, `Map` should throw, if it's not a typo.

Comment: @Yoshi good catch! Is not the issue causing the hook not updating

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with the `useEffect` hook and state update. Does `weatherData` state have a nested `weatherData` property? Can you share that JSON response?

Comment: Please share that JSON response

Comment: @claytonnes just add loading state variable in useEffect Dependecy array getWeather();
    }, [loading]) .... it will re-render your component when ever loading state change

Comment: Added part of json response in post!

Comment: @claytonnes Thanks for sharing the JSON response example, this confirms you at least maintain your `weatherData` state invariant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`renderForecastTable` consumes an argument and attempts to destructure a `weatherData` property, but it is passed the `weatherData` state array, `renderForecastTable(weatherData)`. Looks like you also have a typo, `weatherData.Map` should probably be `weatherData.map`, with a lowercase "map" function. Since the `weatherData` is defined as an array I'll assume you meant to simply pass it to the `renderForecastTable` function.

Consume `weatherData` array, no destructuring and fix "map" typo.

```
const renderForecastTable = (weatherData) => (
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Tid</th><th>Temperatur</th><th>Vind</th><th>Nederbörd</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {
        weatherData.map(hour => 
            <tr>
                <td>{hour.Time}</td><td>{hour.Temp}</td>
                <td>{hour.WindSpeed} m/s {hour.WindDirection} grader</td>
                <td>{hour.AvgPrecipitationIntensity} mm</td>
            </tr>)
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
);
```

`fetch` can return rejected promises and there could be errors processing the response, so you should surround the fetching logic in a `try/catch`.

```
const Weather = (props) => {
    const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const location = useLocation();

    useEffect(() => {
        const getWeather = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(`weather`);
                const json = await response.json();
                setWeatherData(json);
            } catch(error) {
                // handle any rejected promises or thrown errors processing response
            } finally {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        }
        getWeather();
    }, [])

    return(
        loading ? null : renderForecastTable(weatherData)
    )
}
```